# How can I get the content inside <div id="App"></div> using Python?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to gather the text of all the stories in League of Legends lore. I'm webscraping the page where all the short stories are listed in order to find their links and then going to those pages and saving the text.

I encountered a problem when using:

```
URL = "https://universe.leagueoflegends.com/es_ES/explore/short-stories/oldest/"
page = requests.get(URL)
html = page.content
champion_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

The resulting HTML file shows this at lines 233-235:

```
<div id="App"></div>
<div id="Preloader"></div>
<div id="Footer"></div>
```

However, when I inspect the page, it is inside that "App" <div> where all the information I need is located. If I download the webpage directly from Chrome, that part of the HTML shows up in the file, but not when using requests.

I've read it has something to do with it being javascript code and being rendered by the client (I don't know anything about javascript so I might be completely wrong). I want to be able to open that "complete" HTML file from my Python script.

Comment: Their page must be client-side rendered. You would need to open the url in a browser first so that the browser can render the content. [More on rendering methods on the web](https://web.dev/rendering-on-the-web/)

Comment: Have you considered using selenium?

Comment: [Their API](https://universe-meeps.leagueoflegends.com/v1/es_es/explore2/index.json) might yield the content you want in the end *`requests.get('https://universe-meeps.leagueoflegends.com/v1/es_es/explore2/index.json').json()`*